# Validate kendoUI DataSourceRequest object in c#

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a tool that's feeding a bunch of gibberish at my site for security purposes, but one thing that is erroring my system out is the DataSourceRequest object in the controller.  for a sample piece of code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
        public async Task<ActionResult> _GetGoodData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            List<GoodData> reqs = await GetGoodDataAsync();
            return Json(reqs.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I will get an error like:

> Invalid property or field - '19451827' for type: GoodData  Type =
>   System.ArgumentException    Source = Kendo.Mvc        at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.MemberAccessTokenExtensions.CreateMemberAccessExpression(IMemberAccessToken
>   token, Expression instance)     at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.ExpressionFactory.MakeMemberAccess(Expression
>   instance, String memberName)     at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.PropertyAccessExpressionBuilder.CreateMemberAccessExpression()
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.Expressions.MemberAccessExpressionBuilderBase.CreateLambdaExpression()
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Infrastructure.Implementation.SortDescriptorCollectionExpressionBuilder.Sort()
>   at
>   Kendo.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.CreateDataSourceResult[TModel,TResult](IQueryable
>   queryable, DataSourceRequest request, ModelStateDictionary modelState,
>   Func`2 selector)

Now my question here is, is there a way to validate the request object to see if it's fields are valid to the object that it's being applied to?

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/handling-server-side-validation-errors-in-your-kendo-ui-grid

Comment: thank you, but that link just talks about validating the Model itself.  i'm looking at validating the DataSourceRequest object itself.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A DataSourceRequest just modifies the query to add paging, sorting and filtering. Your issue could be that you are grabbing a `List<GoodData>` rather than an IEnumerable or IQueryable. Try something like `return Json(reqs.AsQueryable().ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` Note the `AsQueryable()`. You could alse try `AsEnumerable()` or modify your repo to return IQueryable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i mean exactly what i said above, i'm looking at validating the request object, the issue isn't inherent to the object i'm returning.  the request object is in the query, like ?sort=&page=1&pageSize=10&group=&filter= , etc.  What if you put pageSize=aw0384u230 ? if you do that, you get something like the kendo error above.  I'm looking for something simliar to 'request.IsValid' that would check the possible request object parameters and tell you if they're a correct type or not

Comment: Didn't realize you were not using the MVC wrappers. In that case, you could check it in the server code above and if it is wrong, do a `ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect page size");`

Comment: Yeah, i am using a mix of the MVC wrappers and not on my site.  My main point above was that a security test was taking every bit of network it sees and feeds it gibberish in the query strings provided. hence my issue.  I know i can check the request object myself manually, my main question was whether or not kendo provided a way of checking itself.  Like my example above of a request.IsValid.  It seems like the answer is no

Comment: Have you posted on the Kendo board?

Comment: No, at the time it wasn't allowing me to do so.  I'll try that again, thank you.